# node error. I have 2 js files and on console I typed "node index.js functions.js"

Tags: javascript, node.js

please check the error below:
D:\web dev\scrimba\mobile app\index.cjs:6
console.log(add(20,30))
^

TypeError: add is not a function

Given below is the code I'm trying to run: (Index.html, index.cjs, functions.js)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reel Time</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300&family=Ultra&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Reel Time</h1>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="text" id="input-field" placeholder="Pulp Fiction">
                <button id="add-button">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="functions.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
//const readlineSync = require (readlineSync)


    const add = require('./functions');
add(20,30)
    
const appSettings = {
    databaseURL: "https://playground-91206-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/"

}
const inputFieldEl = document.getElementById("input-field")
const addButtonEl = document.getElementById("add-button")

addButtonEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let inputValue = inputFieldEl.value
    
    console.log(`${inputValue} added to database`)
})
```

---

```
 //const readlineSync = require (readlineSync)

module.export =  function add(a,b) {
   return a + b
```

}

Comment: You are trying to run as a Nodejs file, though by default nodejs doesn't support  es6 "import" syntax. Try using it on the browser by opening the index.html file

Comment: I have added the extension .cjs for the index.js file and instead of "import" I mentioned "require" in the above code. please check now it shows that "add is not a function" I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are you actually trying to assign to `module.export` or was that a typo? Nodejs wants it to be named `exports` regardless of whether there is only one export.

Comment: What file exactly did you try to run? Nothing in the code you show seems to contain the code producing the error ...

Comment: I tried to run index.html in the browser and from inspect I opened the console but the add function's result should show up in the console right, but it's not showing up.

Comment: So, here in the above code, I was trying to run it in node, but when I tried it was showing the above error in node, so tried in the browser console but still did not show any result.  Please advise.